# Encriptación en PHP con murciélago

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, encriptación

Tengo una duda en cuanto a el método de encriptación murciélago enfocado al manejo de vectores, if y count. ¿Me podrían ayudar con información que me ayude en el desarrollo de esto?

La idea sería que quedara [así](http://www.gentedelsur.cl/scout/murcielago.htm), ¿qué debo hacer? Esto es lo que tengo hasta el momento, también quisiera saber ¿qué puedo mejorar en este código?

Mi JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    alert("Listo para usarse");
});

function crypting()
{
    var cadena=$("#chain").val();

    $.ajax({
        url:"../php/crypt_code.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:{"words":cadena},
        success:function(valor){
            $("#list").append("<li><a href='#' id='items'>"+valor+"</a></li>");
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("Error en el Ajax");
        },
    });
}
```

Y este es el código PHP:

```
<?php
    $palabra = $_POST['words'];
    $vector_palabra = str_split($palabra);

    for ($i=0; $i < count($vector_palabra); $i++) {
        if ($vector_palabra[$i] == "m" || $vector_palabra[$i]== "M") {
            $vector_palabra[$i] = str_replace("m","6", $vector_palabra[$i]);
            $vector_palabra[$i] = str_replace("M", "6", $vector_palabra[$i]);
        }
        elseif ($vector_palabra[$i] == "u" || $vector_palabra[$i]== "U") {
            $vector_palabra[$i] = str_replace("u","7", $vector_palabra[$i]);
            $vector_palabra[$i] = str_replace("U", "7", $vector_palabra[$i]);
        }
        elseif ($vector_palabra[$i] == "r"|| $vector_palabra[$i]== "R") {
            $vector_palabra[$i] = str_replace("r","8", $vector_palabra[$i]); 
            $vector_palabra[$i] = str_replace("R", "8", $vector_palabra[$i]);
        }
        elseif ($vector_palabra[$i]== "c" || $vector_palabra[$i]== "C") {
            $vector_palabra[$i] = str_replace("c", "9", $vector_palabra[$i]);
            $vector_palabra[$i] = str_replace("C", "9", $vector_palabra[$i]);
        }
        elseif ($vector_palabra[$i] == "i" || $vector_palabra[$i]== "I") {
            $vector_palabra[$i] = str_replace("i", "0", $vector_palabra[$i]);
            $vector_palabra[$i] = str_replace("I", "0", $vector_palabra[$i]);
        }
        elseif ($vector_palabra[$i] == "e" || $vector_palabra[$i]== "E") {
            $vector_palabra[$i] = str_replace("e", "1", $vector_palabra[$i]);
            $vector_palabra[$i] = str_replace("E", "1", $vector_palabra[$i]);
        }
        elseif ($vector_palabra[$i] == "l" || $vector_palabra[$i]== "L") {
            $vector_palabra[$i] = str_replace("l", "2", $vector_palabra[$i]);
            $vector_palabra[$i] = str_replace("L", "2", $vector_palabra[$i]);
        }
        elseif($vector_palabra[$i] == "a" || $vector_palabra[$i]== "A"){
            $vector_palabra[$i] = str_replace("a", "3", $vector_palabra[$i]);
            $vector_palabra[$i] = str_replace("A", "3", $vector_palabra[$i]);
        }
        elseif($vector_palabra[$i] == "g" || $vector_palabra[$i]== "G"){
            $vector_palabra[$i] = str_replace("g", "4", $vector_palabra[$i]);
            $vector_palabra[$i] = str_replace("G", "4", $vector_palabra[$i]);
        }
        elseif($vector_palabra[$i] == "o" || $vector_palabra[$i]== "O"){
            $vector_palabra[$i] = str_replace("o", "5", $vector_palabra[$i]);
            $vector_palabra[$i] = str_replace("O", "5", $vector_palabra[$i]);
        }
        elseif($vector_palabra[$i] == " "){
            $vector_palabra[$i] = str_replace(" ", "*", $vector_palabra[$i]);
        }

    }

    $word_crypted = implode($vector_palabra);

    echo $word_crypted;
?>
```

Comment: Hola, dr_trejos1996, lamentablemente esta no es una página donde se pueden hacer pedidos de código. Por favor investiga un poco más, avanza con tu código y si tienes algún problema específico puedes regresar y preguntar para poder ayudarte. Por favor lee: [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 7):

El método Murciélago (o la clave Murciélago) es un método de encriptación básico que consiste en buscar una palabra que contenga las cinco vocales (por ejemplo: Murciélago, aceituno, eucalipto, euforia, etc.) y asignar un valor numérico a cada letra de la palabra, entonces para encriptar una frase se reemplaza cada letra por su valor numérico.

> Nota - existen numerosas variantes para este método: reemplazar por números/otras letras/símbolos, sólo reemplazar las vocales, asignar valores a todas las letras y no exclusivamente a las que forman parte de la clave... El ejemplo que presento creo que es el más extendido si buscas en Internet y uno de los más sencillos también.

El algoritmo es simple:

1. Busca una palabra que servirá de clave y que cumpla las siguientes condiciones:

   - Debe contener todas las vocales
   - Debe tener 10 letras o menos (o un máximo de 10 letras diferentes)
2. Asigna valores numéricos a cada letra y guárdalos en un almacén de datos
3. Atraviesa la cadena a encriptar y para cada letra

   1. Busca su equivalente en el almacén
   2. Si existe, cambia la letra por su equivalente
   3. Si no existe, deja la letra como está
4. Devuelve la cadena encriptada

Así en el caso de la palabra Murciélago, los valores serían:

```
M U R C I E L A G O
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
```

Y si por ejemplo queremos encriptar la frase "Bienvenido a StackOverflow", el resultado sería "B56nv65d0 8 St84k0v63f70w":

```
Bienvenido a StackOverflow
 ||  | | | |   || | || ||
 56  6 5 0 8   84 0 63 70
 ||  | | | |   || | || ||   
B56nv6n5d0 8 St84k0v63f70w
```

La implementación variará dependiendo del lenguaje de programación usado y de la estrategia que quieras seguir. Espero que esto te sirva como guía para empezar.

---

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**. Analizando el código que compartes, podrías simplificarlo notablemente siguiendo estos pasos:

- **Elimina la redundancia y simplifica el reemplazo de valores**. `$vector_palabra` es un array cuyos elementos son letras (una letra solo porque estás usando `str_split`). Eso quiere decir que estas dos líneas son redundantes:

  ```
  $vector_palabra[$i] = str_replace("m","6", $vector_palabra[$i]);
  $vector_palabra[$i] = str_replace("M", "6", $vector_palabra[$i]);
  ```

  será el uno o el otro, pero se realizan los dos. Además como sólo es una letra, no necesitas usar `str_replace`, simplemente usa una asignación:

  ```
  $vector_palabra[$i] = "6";
  ```
- **Usa [`strtolower`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) para simplificar la comparación** al hacer que la letra comparada esté en minúsculas. Así la comparación lógica pasaría de ser:

  ```
  $vector_palabra[$i] == "a" || $vector_palabra[$i]== "A"
  ```

  a algo más sencillo como:

  ```
  strtolower($vector_palabra[$i]) == "a"
  ```
- Incluso mejor: **usa un `switch...case`** en lugar de hacer `if...else if...else if...`. El resultado será el mismo, pero más fácil de leer:

  ```
  switch(strtolower($vector_palabra[$i])) {
      case "m": $vector_palabra[$i] = "6"; break;
      case "u": $vector_palabra[$i] = "7"; break;
      ...
  ```

Sólo con esos cambios, el código se reduce considerablemente:

```
<?php
        $palabra = $_POST['words'];;
        $vector_palabra = str_split($palabra);

        for ($i=0; $i < count($vector_palabra); $i++) {

            switch(strtolower($vector_palabra[$i])) {
                case "m": $vector_palabra[$i] = "6"; break;
                case "u": $vector_palabra[$i] = "7"; break;
                case "r": $vector_palabra[$i] = "8"; break;
                case "c": $vector_palabra[$i] = "9"; break;
                case "i": $vector_palabra[$i] = "0"; break;
                case "e": $vector_palabra[$i] = "1"; break;
                case "l": $vector_palabra[$i] = "2"; break;
                case "a": $vector_palabra[$i] = "3"; break;
                case "g": $vector_palabra[$i] = "4"; break;
                case "o": $vector_palabra[$i] = "5"; break;
                case " ": $vector_palabra[$i] = "*"; break;
            }
        }

        $word_crypted = implode($vector_palabra);

        echo $word_crypted;
```